# On Java how do I create a folder and create text documents inside them?

Tags: java, file, directory

Im using Java eclipse and I wanted to know how I can have a java program create a folder with a text file inside of it so I can print data into it.

I need my java program to create a folder in the C Drive called test with a text file inside - thanks if you can help!

Comment: No worries I figured it out - I just needed to create them separately!

Comment: there is lot of questions related to this.plz search first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String path = "C:\\test\\text.txt";
File f = new File(path);
f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
try {
    f.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```